# jquery animate() not starting from current position in FIREFOX

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, position, offset

UPDATE: I just realized the code works as expected in safari/chrome, just not firefox (25.0)

im making a slideshow with panels that swipe horizontally.

i expect animate() to a relative position to START at the current position but its immediately moving my element to a different position, then animating from there.

```
$('section').eq(0).animate({left:'-=500px'},500);
```

this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ySEZe/1/ shows the issue

i suspect the css is to blame ("margin: auto"?) ...if the css seems a little convoluted, the panels are centered, vert and horiz, as well as responsive to the browser size and i finally got that part to work, so any css changes need to not break that.

```
section {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 180px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;  
  padding:0px;
}
```

below is another angle on the problem:

```
var div1 = $('section').eq(0);
var pos = div1.position();
div1.animate({left:''+pos.left+'px',opacity:'1'},0);
```

at work http://jsfiddle.net/AzXW5/3/

that animates the panel to a new position, rather than to where it already is.  basically it puts the panel to the point it had jumped to when i tried to animate() it.  i assume there is some kind of screen offset happening i dont understand.

i've found i can get back to my starting position by animating to left:0 instead of trying to store the current pos.left and returning to it.  but i still get an ugly jump in my animation.  anyone know whats going on?

Comment: you also get the same problem on IE :/

Answer (score 0):

**what if i told you...**

That you don't need the current pos?

```
$('#first-slide').click(function(){
    var df = 500;
    $(this).animate({left:'-='+df+'px',opacity:'0.0'}, {
        duration: df,
        complete : function(){
            $(this).animate({left:'+='+df+'px',opacity:'1'},df); 
        }
    });
});
```

but if you click it multiple times both of those will break, and not go to the intended position.

**so what about something like this?**

```
$('.slides section').first().click(function(){
    var df = 500;
    $(this)//get element
    .stop(true,false)//prevent buildup
    .animate({left:'-'+df+'px',opacity:'0'},df)//out
    .delay(0)//pause between animations
    .animate({left:'0px',opacity:'1'},df);//back
});
```

**css**

```
.slides,.slides section{height:100px;width:180px;position:absolute}
.slides{margin:auto;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0}
.slides section{background-color:#f00}
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/7mk4n/

Comment: when i tried your jsfiddle (in firefox) it did the same thing as mine.  it snapped suddenly to the right, then animated from that position.  if i look at it in chrome, it does just what i want.  same as my version.

Comment: you're right. it's the `right:0` that causes it. right before it animates it jumps to the right. lets see if we can position it centered without using the `top,left,right,bottom` hack.

Comment: wow, thanks!  the solution does work but i couldn't plug in those kind of values and get the element to stay in the center the way i wanted.  the solution for me was to just change the position from absolute to relative, which broke my layout also, but then i placed my <section> into another <div> that had the hacky centering i needed.  relative positioning fixed the animation, but broke the centering in a way i was able to fix with an additional container.

Comment: actually my solution doesnt work.  because now im animating the container div which has absolute positioning anyway so it does the same thing.  if i animate the inner <section> it gets cut off at the boundary of the container as it moves and i want it to look like its going offscreen.

Comment: im sure your way works, but i have a lot of additional code and when i plug it in to mine i cant make it work.  maybe i need to experiment more.

Comment: i had overflow:hidden on my container.  removing that it seems i can animate the inner part and it does what i want.  so far!

Comment: I've updated the answer and fiddle for what I think you're trying to do, check it out.